# Vue.js/Nuxt.js - How to pass props to slots?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

So i have one grandparent component which has this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <Question qtype="single" qroot="1">
        <Answer qpoints="5" aid="1" qcorrect>Option 1</Answer>
        <Answer qpoints="0" aid="2">Option 2</Answer>
      </Question>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
</style>
<script>
import Question from "~/components/render/Question";
import Answer from "~/components/render/Answer";
export default {
  components: {
    Question,
    Answer
  }
};
</script>
```

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
        <slot v-bind="$props"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
</style>
<script>
export default {
  props: ['qtype','qroot']
};
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{$props}}
    <li style="clear: left;">
      <input v-if="qtype == 'single'" :id="'qid-'+qid" type="radio" :name="qroot" :value="qid" style="float:left" />
      <input v-if="qtype == 'multiple'" :id="'qid-'+qid" type="checkbox" :name="qroot" :value="qid" style="float:left" />
      <label style="float:left;margin-left:5px" :for="'qid-'+qid">
        <slot></slot>
      </label>
    </li>
  </div>
</template>
<style>
</style>
<script>
export default {
   props: ["qtype", "qpoints", "qcorrect", "qroot", "aid"]
};
</script>
```

I tried to use v-bind, regular prop passing like this ':qtype="qtype"' but it doesn't seem to work.
How can i pass "qtype" and "qroot" props to the grandchild component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you desire using [Scoped Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).

First of all we need properly name the prop binding in `Question.vue`. Let's call call it `slotProps` for now.

```
<!-- Question.vue -->
<slot :slotProps="$props"></slot>
```

Now let's do all the magic in the main file.
Now remember how I mentioned the Scoped Slots? Using theirs API we can do this. I reckon the codes speaks for itself.

```
<!-- main file -->
<Question qtype="single" qroot="1" v-slot="{ slotProps }">
  <Answer :qtype="slotProps.qtype" :qroot="slotProps.qroot" qpoints="5" aid="1" qcorrect>Option 1</Answer>
  <Answer :qtype="slotProps.qtype" :qroot="slotProps.qoot" qpoints="0" aid="2">Option 2</Answer>
</Question>
```

**Disclaimer**: this works only with `Vue 2.6` or higher!

Not convinced it works? Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ejdrien/n16ct0rL/3/) out.